# How to prevent buttons from moving when resizing window?

Tags: java, layout

I am making a snake game and I am just setting up the base of it. My program runs fine, but it doesn't load when I run it right away. To fix this, usually just resizing the window loads everything in. However, when I resize the window, the buttons move to the top of the snake game grid, and moves off the side where I put them. When I continue to make the window smaller, the buttons continue to move as it would with a layout. I want the buttons to stay on the side, but I am confused as to why they are moving as I am pretty sure I didn't put a layout in my code. I have been searching for one, and I couldn't find it. How can I prevent the buttons from moving when I resize the window so the buttons stay away to the side of the grid?

```
package snake;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Panel extends JPanel {
    private Game myGame;
    private Image fon, telo, golova, ob, endG;
    private JButton btn1, btn2;
    private JLabel lb;
    private Timer tmDraw;
    
    public void startPanel() {
        try{
            fon = ImageIO.read(new File("./fon.png"));
            telo = ImageIO.read(new File("./telo.png"));
            golova = ImageIO.read(new File("./golova.png"));
            ob = ImageIO.read(new File("./ob.png"));
            endG = ImageIO.read(new File("./endG.png"));
            
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        
        myGame = new Game();
        myGame.start();
        
        btn1 = new JButton("New Game");
        btn1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        btn1.setFont(new Font("serif", 0, 20));
        btn1.setBounds(630, 30, 150, 50);
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
            }
        });
        add(btn1);
        
        btn2 = new JButton("Exit");
        btn2.setForeground(Color.red);
        btn2.setFont(new Font("serif", 0, 20));
        btn2.setBounds(630, 100, 150, 50);
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        add(btn2);
        
        lb = new JLabel("Score: 0");
        lb.setForeground(Color.blue);
        lb.setFont(new Font("Serif", 0, 30));
        lb.setBounds(630, 200, 150, 50);
        add(lb);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        gr.drawImage(fon, 0, 0, 800, 640, null);
        gr.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for(int i = 0; i<31;i++) {
            gr.drawLine(10+i*20, 10, 10+i*20, 610);
            //gr.drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
            gr.drawLine(10, 10+i*20, 610, 10+i*20);
        }
    }
}
```

If my other code is needed, I can provide that too, however I don't think it's needed or has anything to do with the problem :)

Comment: *but it doesn't load when I run it right away.* - then you are doing something wrong. Probably you add the components to the frame after making the frame visible. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. **Don't attempt to use a null layout and setBounds(...)**. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers and by default a JPanel does have a layout manager. If you want the buttons on the left, then you need two panels: 1) one for the buttons with an appropriate layout manager support vertical compnents 2) the game panel can be added to the CENTER.

Comment: *I don't think it's needed or has anything to do with the problem* - it is always needed. Until a problem is solved you don't not what part of the code is causing a problem. Post a proper [mre] if you need more help. So start with a simple JFrame. Create your panel with the button and add it to the frame using `BorderLayout.LINE_START`. If it doesn't work, then you have a simple 20 line class to post showing what you have done. Once the buttons display as expected, then you add your game panel to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Comment: Okay. The program works now. Thank you for your help and for clarifying! :)